# App window and clickable background

Tags: android, screen

When user start the application, I just want to show a button. User can continiue to use phone . 
Example :  (problem is icon is not clickable)

```
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

[image]

Comment: Can you detail it a little more? It almost looks like you want to create a widget. https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/widgets.html

Comment: I know but I don't want to Widget. For instance, that button can seen on status bar or other applications. This is what I want. (example: https://www.mobario.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW

"android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" use this permission in main-feast

```
    windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

        Button btn = new ImageView(this);

        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
windowManager.addView(btn, params);
```

Comment: Thanks mate. I tested it but button and background are not clickable.

Comment: It will take only button space in screen,if you want but click add onclicklistener() to button

Comment: Oh true. But what I want is : a button is on all windows. Only a button. (example app: https://www.mobario.com/)